# Efficiently concatenate many large 3-dimensional arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have approximately 100 `numpy` arrays. Each of them is having shape of (100, 40000, 4). I want to concatenate these arrays along first axis, i.e., `axis=0` into one big array efficiently.

### Approach 1

I used `np.concatenate` as shown below-

```
def concatenate(all_data):
    for index, data in enumerate(all_data):
        if index == 0:
            arr = data.copy()
        else:
            arr = np.concatenate((arr, data), axis=0)
    return arr
```

### Approach 2

I created panel in pandas and then used `pd.concat` as shown below-

```
def concatenate(all_data):
    for index, data in enumerate(all_data):
        if index == 0:
            pn = pd.Panel(data)
        else:
            pn = pd.concat([pn, pd.Panel(data)])
    return pn # numpy array can be acquired from pn.values
```

The second approach seems faster than first one. However, this approach shows deprecated warning while creating `pd.Panel`.

I want to know if there exists better way to concatenate large 3-dimensional arrays in python.

Comment: What type is `all_data` (list or array or something else)? If array, what's its shape?

Comment: It is a list of `numpy` arrays!

Comment: It is a list of `numpy` array where the shape of each `numpy` array is `(100, 40000, 4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `np.concatenate()` repeatedly is an anti-pattern.  Instead, try this:

```
np.concatenate(all_data)
```

Simple, fast.